# How should one handle deep objects with EF+Web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

This is my first question here, so be gentle.

I have a database model consisting of about 60 objects describing information and various features of a an industrial process. The end result is approx. 10-level deep objects.

My intention was to

- send a top level object to the client in JSON

  two-way bind said object (in angular, but nvm that) and manipulate it

  make the client's AJAX calls refer to that top-level object

  rebuild said object via one or two constructor calls in the Web API

  alter the object and save the changes via a top-level object method

My solution was to create an additional layer of objects that are based on the EF ones to allow omitting/adding data from/in the objects being sent to the client at will, circumventing issues with circular references and other problems caused by eager/lazy loading. These objects are fed to the Web API.

Now here's where the trouble begins:
as a result of the additional layer, reconstruction of the EF objects from the additional layer ones is necessary whenever saving changes in the EF objects down the chain. It is getting increasingly arduous to keep up with all of this.

The objects are highly interconnected and constrained. Should I just write extensions for the EF objects to emulate the features of the additional layer? 
If that's the case, won't the JavaScriptSerializer try to serialize all the  objects in all of the relationships (where the serialized object's key is defined as a FK in another object)? Because that's what I've gathered from the error messages.

Or am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a disconnected application like yours, I'd **remove *all* navigation properties**. They may seem convenient at first, but will cause headaches along the way.

I believe that accessing all *entities* via `Id` is the way to go.
You can write a **JavaScript class** which is responsible for **receiving** entities per `Id` and can therefore cache them.
So each time you need an *entity* on the client, you get it through this class.

This would result in having one controller for each entity.

Another advantage is that you don't always have to send and receive the whole object graph, which seems like a lot of data (10 levels deep is a lot).

---

> won't the JavaScriptSerializer try to serialize all the objects in all of the relationships

Yes it will. That's one reason why objects with navigation properties, especially circular ones, are very difficult to serialize.

Comment: This actually confirmed a lot of what I suspected in the first place. The amount of boilerplate for the controllers kind of sucks though, but it makes sense to not send the whole object every time (even if it's <10kB or so). Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't setting RecursionLimit=1 prevent the serializer from walking the tree?